# How do I check for a session variable in flask repeatedly across the application?

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I'm looking for an efficient way to check a session variable for each view.  I can do it like below per the docs, but is there a global function or decorator that could extract the `username` without repeating the same lines?

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    if 'username' in session:   # this is repeated in every view
        username = session['username'] # this is repeated in every view
    return 'You are not logged in'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your guess is correct. A decorator is a way to review the session and react to the result. In the example below, the user is redirected to the appropriate route based on the decorator if the user is not logged in. If a username is stored in the session, the decorated route is called.

If the login is optional for the respective route, it is public and no decorator is required. But it might be necessary to ask if the user is logged in.

```
from flask import (
    redirect,
    session,
    url_for
)
from functools import wraps

# ...

def is_authenticated():
    username = session.get('username')
    return username and len(username.strip()) > 0

def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if not is_authenticated():
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

# Add the state query function to the jinja context.
app.jinja_env.globals.update(is_authenticated=is_authenticated)

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    # your login code here!

@app.route('/secret')
@login_required
def secret():
    return 'You are logged in.'

@app.route('/public')
def public():
    if is_authenticated():
        return 'User is authenticated'
    return 'User is not authenticated'
```

This code is used to check within the template whether the user is logged in.

```
    {% if is_authenticated() %}
      User is authenticated.
    {% else %}
      User is not authenticated.
    {% endif %}
```

If you really want to ask for the session variable before each route, the [before_request](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Flask.before_request) decorator might be a solution. In this case you cannot avoid storing variables in the [g object](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/appcontext/#storing-data) to use them in your routes. However, this goes beyond your example or unnecessarily complicates the code as it only becomes necessary to use additional data.
I think the code I gave should be enough for simple purposes.
For more complex environments I recommend you take a look at [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [Flask-Security](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/).

Comment: What would the flow be if the login is optional?  Would you create a @login_optional decorator and have just check the session value in each view?

Comment: @user1961 I've edited my answer and hope I was able to help you.

Comment: Great this authenticated function will work, and it's more efficient than checking the session every endpoint I believe.